# need help with Countertop LED Backlighting

Tags: led, led-driver, dimmer

I run a general contracting company and my salesperson bit off more than we could chew on this job lighting up a translucent countertop. The wrong parts were ordered and I am now in a spot that I am not sure if I can make this work or not.

To start I have 24 of these flexible LED sheet lights that are already installed underneath a countertop in this island. Getting to these panels and wiring again would be near impossible.

[image]

Here is the link to those sheet lights that already installed:
[Sheet lights](https://www.hardwareresources.com/task-lighting-power/clearance/flexible-sheet-lighting/l-fsl-15w.html)

The sheet lights are 15 W each, Totaling up to 360 W, I know that I need my driver to have 20 % overage which would be 432 W.

I was looking at this Mean Well driver that is 480 W, That also allows a 0-10 V dimmer, the output has 2 channels from what I can tell, so I am not sure if would be able to bridge the channels in order to get the wattage that I need?

[Driver Specs](https://led.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=HLG-480H)

As far as the dimmer goes, since this will be installed inside of a customer home I need to confirm what look they want, but I will most likely propose to them to use this Lutron dimmer switch. [Dimmer switch](https://www.prolighting.com/catalog/product/view/id/106725/s/dvstv-br/category/3210/)

as far as the rest of the wiring for the dimmer and power supply I am not concerned I just want to see if this combination would work or not? This is above my skill range but want to make sure things are done correctly.

Comment: That power supply will work. But it looks like it's only single channel output. But even if is it is 2 channels, just split the load between both outputs. A bigger issue I see is that you mention, it's almost impossible to get to the LED panels without ripping the counter apart. What's your plan if and when the panels need to be replaced?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about code compliance. Class 2 power supplies at 24v are limited to 4A, but you've built a 15A lighting circuit. Is that safe, or even allowed where you live?

Comment: Seems like a diy stack exchange question…